# Classpath for MySQL connector to JDBC-can't load the driver

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I was trying to connect to MySQL using JDBC API. I have downloaded the MySQL driver which is the "mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin jar" file. My OS is Windows 7 and I have set the Classpath of Java to following path:

```
"E:\Myclass"
```

I have copied the above jar file to this folder.
Then I have written the following code to test if I can load the driver.

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoadDriver {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        // The newInstance() call is a work around for some
        // broken Java implementations

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // handle the error
        System.out.println("Unable to load Driver Class");
        return;
    }
}
}
```

### I expect everything should be working fine but I always get the "Unable to load Driver Class". Can anyone point out where was wrong? Thanks

Note: Thanks for all your answers. I have solved the problem. Since I am using Eclipse, I have add the JAR file to the classpath of the Eclipse.

Comment: Don't call `newInstance()`

Comment: Tried that, still doesn't work

Comment: Explictly declare the class path to point to my JAR's

Comment: @user3225698 r u running it frm cmd ??

Comment: No, I am running with Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to include the JAR in your classpath:

```
java -jar yourdriver.jar LoadDriver
```

JARs are filesystems. They should be added to your classpath the same way you add directories. Only classes will be loaded from the classpath you specified.

Comment: My JAR is in the classpath, I have copied the Jar file to the classpath which in my case is:"E:\Myclass"

Comment: To load the classes you need to have not the JAR inside a directory which is in your classpath, but as part of your classpath. Try the suggestion above, or set CLASSPATH to include your JAR as well (`CLASSPATH=E:/Myclass;yourdriver.jar`)

Answer (score 0):

Use the below cmd to run it

```
java -cp E:\Myclass\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar; LoadDriver
```

As mentioned the mysql jar exist @ `E:\Myclass\mysql-connector-java-5.1.28-bin.jar` , just set in the classpath and run it